# Multiple sites in same subfolder

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, subsites

I have multiple very similar drupal sites (each for a specific year of some project): 2012.somain.tld, 2013.domain.tld, etc. Their files are organized in subdirectories (2012, 2013, etc.) of `public_html` directory of my hosting.

I'm trying to make them all work via .htaccess settings. I write the following code for every site:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2013\.domain\.tld$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2013/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2013/$1 [L]
```

The sites then open and at first everything seems fine, but then I realize that all URLs within site contain the subfolder name. What used to be http://2013.domain.tld/news/123 now http://2013.domain.tld/2013/news/123. And Drupal thinks that it is in the subdirectory and makes all paths reative to it.

[image]

What can I do to make things work properly, without this /2013/ in every URL?